# Maven proxy configuration with Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am using Nexus and have configured maven-proxy and maven-hosted repositories, added them to a group repo and using that repo through settings.xml. Now when a new dependency is added in pom, maven-proxy goes to maven central and downloads it. However, I do not want this.

My goal is to stop replying on Maven central completely, but I know it won't work until my hosted repository contains everything that maven needs.

Issue is that Maven plugins like compiler, clean, jar etc. downloads tons of dependencies on its own. If I remove connection to maven proxy, how do I get all that list and then how do I make sure that I put whatever is needed in my hosted repository ?

Should I even try to put such artifacts in my hosted repo ? Is there any other better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do that manually, the number of artifacts is way too large.

You can let Maven download all needed artifacts, then copy that from a remote to a hosted repository and work with that (until you need something new).

But it is still painful. I would not do that.

If your concern is security, I would use an open source security scanner instead of blocking internet access altogether.

Comment: Thanks @fabian, this was helpful.